# how to extract first line of a textarea content

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
let a = first line of `txt`;
$('#target').text(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class='txt' id='txt'>
sky sky
blue blue
red red
</textarea>

<p id='target'></p>
```

Ho to extract the first line of text inside the textarea.

Result should be:
`sky sky`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lines are split at `\n`, so this should work.

```js
var lines = $('#txt').val().split('\n');//gives all lines
    var firstLine=lines[0];
    console.log('firstLine:',firstLine);
    $("#firstLine").html(firstLine)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class='txt' id='txt'>
sky sky
blue blue
red red
</textarea>

<h3 id="firstLine"></h3>
```